# R function not assigning values

Tags: r, tidyverse

Using the Boston Housing Data, train.csv, from Kaggle [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data). I tried to write a function to change the value of the GarageYrBlt column to 0 if the row contains an NA value or is 0 already and a 1 otherwise.

This column contains the year a garage was built, but has missing values as well as zeros.

I'm relatively new to R and cobbled together the function below to try and substitute the values in this column.

```
library(tidyverse)
housing_prices <- read_csv('../input/train.csv')


garage <- function(x) {
    for (i in 1:length(x)){
    if (is.na(x[i])) {
       x[i] = 0}
    else if (x[i] > 0) { 
        x[i] = 1} 
    else x[i]=0}
}

garage(housing_prices$GarageYrBlt)
```

If I place a print(x) statement before the last curly brace of the function I can see that the logic is working correctly. However, it is not assigning the values back to the GarageYrBlt column. I know I'm missing something simple here.

Also, if anyone knows of a vectorized way to accomplish this or has any other tips in general, they are always greatly appreciated.

Comment: Functions return the last value. Put `x` or `return(x)` at the end of your function so that your modified `x` will be returned out of the function.

Comment: Tried putting it at the end of the if else block and then tried putting it at the end of the for loop. No dice both ways. If I place it outside of the for loop, but still inside the function definition I can see the right output returned, but when I check the tibble column it is not transformed.

Comment: You also have to assign the result. If `x` is `1`, `x + 1` prints 2, but `x` is still `1`. If you want to modify `x` you do `x = x + 1` or `x <- x + 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions return the last value. Put `x` or `return(x)` at the end of your function so that your modified `x` will be returned out of the function.

```
garage <- function(x) {
    for (i in 1:length(x)) {
        if (is.na(x[i])) {
            x[i] = 0}
        else if (x[i] > 0) { 
            x[i] = 1
        } 
        else x[i] = 0
    }
    x
}
```

Then, if you want the result assigned, you need to assign it with `=` or `<-`

```
housing_prices$GarageYrBlt = garage(housing_prices$GarageYrBlt)
```

Of course, we can use vectorized `ifelse` instead of `if` in a for loop:

```
housing_prices$GarageYrBlt = ifelse(is.na(housing_prices$GarageYrBlt), 0,
     ifelse(housing_prices$GarageYrBlt > 0, 1, 0))
```

Since you put the `tidyverse` tag, a nicer way to do it in `dplyr` would be to use `case_when`:

```
housing_prices %>% 
  mutate(GarageYrBlt = case_when(
    is.na(GarageYrBlt) ~ 0,
    GarageYrBlt > 0 ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
))
```

Alternately, `coalesce()` is a nice `dplyr` utility to fill in `NA` values, so we could do

```
housing_prices %>% 
  mutate(GarageYrBlt = ifelse(coalesce(GarageYrBlt, 0) > 0, 1, 0))
```

Or, even fancier, we could use the default conversions of `TRUE` to 1 and `FALSE` to 0:

```
housing_prices %>% 
  mutate(GarageYrBlt = as.integer(coalesce(GarageYrBlt, 0) > 0))
```

Comment: Dang G! And by G I mean @Gregor, AND Gangsta. Thank you for the thorough  explanation. Can't believe I missed the <-. I should have caught that. Your examples are great and I can follow along up until the coalesce(). I'll read up on mutate() and coalesce().

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
housing_prices <- housing_prices %>%
    mutate(GarageYrBlt = if_else(is.na(GarageYrBlt),0,GarageYrBlt)
```